# Vjust in ggplot: axis text disappears or cannot be moved

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to move the x axis text from the bottom to the top of a table created using ggplot. When I use "top" or "bottom" the text disappears. When I try to use numbers between 0 and 1, the text doesn't move. I got the text to move to the middle of the table using extremely high numbers (16166525334) but as I took this out to the thousands place I could not get it to move any further (obviously that is not a great solution but I'm going for broke).

Why does the location stay in the same place, even when I change the location per the directions set by element_text()? Could it be a problem with the data structure? Sorry I cannot include the exact data since this is for work. Is there another way to change the location of the axis text?

Code:

```
data_table <- ggplot(m, aes(x = m$Var1, y = m$Var2),label=format(m$Freq)) +
theme_bw() + 
geom_text(size = 3.5,label=m$Freq) + 
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.position = "", panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(vjust="top")) + 
xlab(NULL) + 
ylab(NULL) 

print(data_table)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You mean you want the x-axis to be at the top of the graph instead of the bottom? If so, see the `cowplot` package and its [vignette on changing axis positions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/axis_position.html).

Comment: Also, you should only refer to column names and not the parent data frame. For example, `x = m$Var1` should be `x = Var1`, etc. You've already fed the `m` data frame to ggplot (`ggplot(m, aes(...)`) so ggplot has `m` in its local environment. Referring to the data frame again subverts that by telling ggplot to go outside the local environment. In addition, change `geom_text(size = 3.5,label=m$Freq)` to `geom_text(size = 3.5, aes(label=Freq))`.

Comment: If you look at `?element_text`, it says "`vjust`: vertical justification (in [0, 1])". Now, I know that it's not completely strict - 0 and 1 are the bottom and top of whatever box it's trying to put the text in and numbers outside of 0 and 1 will move it outside of the box. But the `vjust` argument is definitely expecting a number - which should make it no surprise that the text disappears when you give it a string like `"top"`.

Comment: Thanks for all the input! I tried cowplot but was still unable to get it in the right position. I was able to hack it with annotate().